# Complex Queries to be solved with nested loop

Tags: griddb

```
SELECT a.column1,b.column2,c.column   FROM table1 JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id JOIN table3 c ON b.id = c.id WHERE a.some_condition = 'value' AND b.another_condition = 123 AND c.yet_another_condition > 456;
```

Need to understand the question using nested loop

Comment: Assuming our complex query to be: 
EXPLAIN
SELECT
  a.column1,
  b.column2,
  c.column3
FROM
  table1 a
JOIN
  table2 b ON a.id = b.id
JOIN
  table3 c ON b.id = c.id
WHERE
  a.some_condition = 'value'
  AND b.another_condition = 123
  AND c.yet_another_condition > 456;